# IOS 6 UITableViewCellEditingStyle Overlapping TableViewCell Labels

Tags: ios6

I am working with IOS 6 UITableView and my problem is that whenever i put the table view into edit mode, the edit control that appears next to the table view cell of deletestyle ( UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) overlaps two labels ( xyzname and xyzcollege ).
I did not have this problem in IOS 5 (with same code).

CODE:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
         [super viewDidLoad]; 
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"friends"ofType:@"plist"];

         NSDictionary *xyz = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

         _names = [xyz objectForKey:@"name"];
         _colls = [xyz objectForKey:@"college"];

         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

     }

     -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
     {
         NSInteger count =_names.count;
         if(self.editing)
         {
             count++;
         }
         return count;
     }

    -(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         saumyaTableViewCell *cell;

         cell = [_saumyaTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"saumyacell"];

         if(indexPath.row < _names.count)
         {
            cell.xyzname.text = [_names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.xyzcollege.text = [_colls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         }
         else
         {

            cell.xyzname.text = @"Add name.";
            cell.xyzcollege.text = @"Add College";
            cell.editingAccessoryType =
            UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
         }
         return cell;
    }


   -(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL) animated
   {

      if( editing != self.editing )
      {
          [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
          [_saumyaTable setEditing:editing animated:animated];

          NSArray *indexes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
          [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_names.count inSection:0]];

          if (editing == YES )
          {
             [_saumyaTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
          }
          else
          {
             [_saumyaTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
          }
       }
    }

   - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row < _names.count)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
 }
```

IMAGE DESCRIPTION:

1.UITableViewCell has two labels(xyzname and xyzcollege)

2.UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete overlaps these two labels when cell goes into edit mode

What is to be done if i want those labels to automatically animate on the right side when my view goes into the edit mode and again animate to their original positions after coming out of the edit mode?

THANK YOU